# Client not receiving hub push with SignalR

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, signalr

I have the following hub:

```
public class MyHub : Hub
{
    public static HubLifetimeManager<MyHub> HubManager { get; private set; }
    public MyHub(HubLifetimeManager<MyHub> hubManager)
    {
        HubManager = hubManager;
    }

    public string SayHello()
    {
        return "hello! " + DateTime.UtcNow;
    }
}
```

and I'm pushing events at a regular interval, like this:

```
private static void TickTimer(object State)
{
    var Time = DateTime.UtcNow.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    var A = MyHub.HubManager;
    if (A != null)
    {
        A.SendAllAsync("Update", new object[] { Time });
    }
}
```

On the client side, I the following code:

```
        var Connection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
            .WithUrl("http://localhost:8000/myhub")
            .Build();

        Connection.On("Update", () => Console.WriteLine("Update")); DOESN'T WORK
        Connection.On("Update", (object[] O) => Console.WriteLine("AA")); DOESN'T WORK EITHER

        var StartAsync = Connection.StartAsync();
        StartAsync.Wait();
```

What did I miss?

---

Update:

I added logging and found this:

> Failed to bind arguments received in invocation '(null)' of 'Update'.
>   System.IO.InvalidDataException: Invocation provides 1 argument(s) but target expects 0.
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Protocol.JsonHubProtocol.BindArguments(JsonTextReader reader, IReadOnlyList`1 paramTypes)

The issue was simply that the parameter list wasn't the same. But unless logging is turned on, SignalR just swallows the errors and nothing is visible.

Comment: Just to rule it out, is `MyHub` definitely being instantiated / `A.SendAllAsync` being called?

Comment: Do you have the generic methods available as used here? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/dotnet-client?view=aspnetcore-2.2#connect-to-a-hub

Can you do `Connection.On<object[]>("Update", (obj) => Console.WriteLine("updated"));`?

Comment: yes, A points to a valid HubLifetimeManager<MyHub> instance and the call goes through. Since I'm on Mac, I don't have fiddler and since the client is C# I can't inspect data through the browser, so the testing is doing blindly. Is there a way to hook to 'any' message coming in?

Comment: @pep, I just tried and the result is the same, the message is not coming through

Comment: Actually - instead of calling `StartAsync.Wait();` can you call `await StartAsync();`?

Comment: Just wondering if it's possible that `Connection.On` is handled on the same thread as the above code and therefore `StartAsync.Wait()` would block it. I'm half guessing fyi, I haven't done much with signalr core. Hopefully someone with working experience can spot it.

Comment: @pep: I just put await Connection.StartAsync(); but it's the same. I'm doing client calls to the hub every second and they go through without problem

Comment: With wireshark I see this: {"type":1,"target":"Update","arguments":["04/23/2019 20:54:03"]}, so the hub is sending the data, the client is somehow not processing it.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
  Connection.On<object[]>("Update", (data) =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine("AA");
                //TO DO
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that you're sending **only one argument**:

> A.SendAllAsync("Update", new object[] { Time });

So I change the `On()` to the following:

```
Connection.On<DateTime>("Update", (s) => Console.WriteLine("AA"+s.ToString()));
```

And it works fine for me

[image]

Comment: yes, the problem was the argument; that's what I have written in the question update. Thanks!